# How print art board output to exact linear dimension with Illustrator CC?

Tags: print-design

I am new to Illustrator with little prior digital art experience. I am in art sign trade and am required to produce artwork (artboard) shapes, types, and lines to an exact area size (say, +/- 1/8 in. or 4 mm).

For example, when I print specifying a 5" × 24" artboard, it prints out about 15% smaller on tiled pages using US-letter inkjet printer. How to create print output to nominally exact sizes? Your help would be the most welcome.

Comment: Also, do you have your document setup and print PPI set the same?

Answer (score -1):

Export the AI file from CC to pdf and print from another desktop/computer using Reader/Acrobat.